# How can I make a smart and dynamic initialization depending on first choice on init in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want define a smart initialization method that it understands the chosen first parameter and adjust itself for it!

Here is my code:

```
struct Test {

    enum Kind { case vertical, horizontal }
    enum VerticalAlignment { case top, center, bottom }
    enum HorizontalAlignment { case leading, center, trailing }
    
    
    // if kind == horizontal then just VerticalAlignment:
    init(kind: Kind, verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment) {
        
    }
    
    // if kind == vertical then just HorizontalAlignment:
    init(kind: Kind, horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment) {
        
    }
    
}
```

As you can see in my codes, I have an initialization parameter called kind, here would be logic, if i chose `.vertical` then I want my second parameter automatically adjust itself to `HorizontalAlignment` type!

The issue with my code is that we can chose `.horizontal` and also get `HorizontalAlignment` type for second parameter!

I want limit my initialization and make it mistake-proof initialization,
my goal is JUST this 2 initialization way:

**. vertical → HorizontalAlignment**

**. horizontal → VerticalAlignment**

---

**How can I have both parameters available for initialization with those limitation?**

### Update: use case

```
struct CustomLineShape: Shape {
    
    let kind: Kind
    let verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment
    let horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment
    

    enum Kind { case vertical, horizontal }
    enum VerticalAlignment { case top, center, bottom }
    enum HorizontalAlignment { case leading, center, trailing }
    
    init(kind: CustomLineShape.Kind, verticalAlignment: CustomLineShape.VerticalAlignment) {
        self.kind = kind
        self.verticalAlignment = verticalAlignment
        self.horizontalAlignment = .center
    }
    
    
    init(kind: CustomLineShape.Kind, horizontalAlignment: CustomLineShape.HorizontalAlignment) {
        self.kind = kind
        self.horizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment
        self.verticalAlignment = .center
    }

    private func verticalFunction(rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        switch verticalAlignment {
        case .top: return rect.minY
        case .center: return rect.midY
        case .bottom: return rect.maxY
        }
    }

    private func horizontalFunction(rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        switch horizontalAlignment {
        case .leading: return rect.minX
        case .center: return rect.midX
        case .trailing: return rect.maxX
        }
    }


    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        switch kind {
        case .horizontal:
            
            return Path { path in

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: verticalFunction(rect: rect)))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: verticalFunction(rect: rect)))
                
            }
            
        case .vertical:
            
            return Path { path in

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: horizontalFunction(rect: rect), y: rect.minY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: horizontalFunction(rect: rect), y: rect.maxY))
                
            }
 
        }
  
    }
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            CustomLineShape(kind: .vertical, horizontalAlignment: .center)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5))
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.black.cornerRadius(5.0))
            


            // Here is the issue! I chose horizontal for kind and still horizontalAlignment is available! Which make no meaning for drawing matter!

            // Logically it must just verticalAlignment be available! For drawing matter!

            CustomLineShape(kind: .horizontal, horizontalAlignment: .center)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5))
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.black.cornerRadius(5.0))
            
        }
        .padding()
         
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm saying that you can just do `enum Alignment { case horizontal(HorizontalAlignment), vertical(VerticalAlignment) }`, and have the initialiser take an `Alignment`. You will be able to access all the same information as before in the initialiser.

Comment: Okay. For the line-drawing code that you are going to write, are you going to have 6 different cases, one for each combination of `Kind` and alignment, or are you going to do the same things for `top` and `leading`, the same things for `bottom` and `trailing` etc? If it's the former, then Yurii Petrov's answer would work. If it's the latter, then that will create a lot of code duplication.

Comment: I have no issue with drawing part! and I think your comment and Yurii Answer helps me. I was hopping side by side initialization, but I think it is not possible.

Comment: There are tricks that you can use to make that possible (e.g. use classes with `static let`s and associated types), but it's kind of hard for me to write an answer without seeing how you are checking these values.

Comment: @Sweeper: Firstly thanks until now for your time! I will update the use case, i would like to have the ultimate answer form you, if it is a thing in swift.

Comment: @Sweeper: I added my use case of my wished initialization!

Comment: Ah, then Yurii Petrov's solution is perfect for you! I'll still post my answer though, since I worked quite hard on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Test {
    
    enum VerticalAlignment { case top, center, bottom }
    enum HorizontalAlignment { case leading, center, trailing }

    enum Kind { case vertical(VerticalAlignment),
                     horizontal(HorizontalAlignment) }
    
    init(kind: Kind) {
        switch kind {
        case .horizontal(let horizontalAlignment):
            switch horizontalAlignment {
            case .center:
                ...
            }
        case .vertical(let verticalAlignment):
            ...
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It solves my issue, I think you made a typo: `vertical(HorizontalAlignment), horizontal(VerticalAlignment)` but no matter it is okay.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: you should definitely use Yurii Petrov's answer rather than what I'm showing here. This is really abusing Swift's features, and kind of overkill for what you are trying to do... My aim is just to show that this sort of thing can be done.

The idea is that you will have a protocol with an associated type:

```
protocol AlignmentProtocol : AnyObject {
    
}

protocol AlignmentKind {
    associatedtype Alignment: AlignmentProtocol
}
```

And then you can write the initialiser's signature as:

```
init<Kind: AlignmentKind>(kind: Kind, alignment: Kind.Alignment) {
```

Now let's write the alignment kind and alignment conformers:

```
final class HorizontalAlignment : AlignmentProtocol {
    
    static let leading = HorizontalAlignment()
    static let center = HorizontalAlignment()
    static let trailing = HorizontalAlignment()
    
    private init() {}
}

final class VerticalAlignment : AlignmentProtocol {
    
    static let top = VerticalAlignment()
    static let center = VerticalAlignment()
    static let bottom = VerticalAlignment()
    
    private init() {}
}

struct HorizontalAlignmentKind : AlignmentKind {
    typealias Alignment = HorizontalAlignment
    
}

struct VerticalAlignmentKind : AlignmentKind {
    typealias Alignment = VerticalAlignment
}
```

Note that there's quite a lot of boilerplate already, since we are not using enums. The reason why we are using classes is because we want to be able to check these in the initialiser, but as you can see from the signature, the `alignment` parameter is of type `Kind.Alignment`. We can't compare the equality of this with e.g. a `HorizontalAlignment` by using `==` directly. `==` only works on things of the same type. If they are classes, however, they have an `ObjectIdentifier`, which I can compare with `===`.

Anyway, we can finish this off by adding some convenient properties, to simulate an enum-like syntax for `AlignmentKind` (e.g. `.horizontal`):

```
extension AlignmentKind where Self == HorizontalAlignmentKind {
    static var horizontal: HorizontalAlignmentKind { .init() }
}

extension AlignmentKind where Self == VerticalAlignmentKind {
    static var vertical: VerticalAlignmentKind { .init() }
}
```

We also overload  `~=` so that we can use `switch` statements with `AlignmentProtocol`s

```
extension AlignmentProtocol {
    static func ~=(pattern: AnyObject, this: Self) -> Bool {
        pattern === this
    }
}
```

This is how you can check those arguments in the initialiser:

```
class Foo {
    init<Kind: AlignmentKind>(kind: Kind, alignment: Kind.Alignment) {
        if kind is HorizontalAlignmentKind {
           // ...
        }
        switch alignment {
        case HorizontalAlignment.leading:
            // ...
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Applying to your real use case, you would probably keep your `Kind` enum, and use an if statement to convert my `AlignmentKind` to your `Kind`, and then do some safe casting on the alignments.

```
if kind is HorizontalAlignmentKind {
    self.kind = .horizontal
} else {
    self.kind = .vertical
}
// VerticalAlignment is my class, not your enum
self.verticalAlignment = (alignment as? VerticalAlignment) ?? .center

// HorizontalAlignment is my class, not your enum
self.horizontalAlignment = (alignment as? HorizontalAlignment) ?? .center
```

Finally, we can do:

```
Foo(kind: .horizontal, alignment: .leading) // compiles

// Type 'HorizontalAlignmentKind.Alignment' (aka 'HorizontalAlignment') has no member 'top'
Foo(kind: .horizontal, alignment: .top)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will study your answer.